# What is the ratio of flipped over normal tiles for the hat polykite tiling?

Tags: geometry, limits, tiling

In the [following video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNaEP2dfeVo) by Pembesita, he mentions at 17:54 that for a certain tiling consisting of 78 hat polykites, there are 66 normal tiles and 12 flipped tiles. Below one can see a screenshot:

[image]

Let $r(n)$ denote the ratio of the amount of flipped hats over the amount of normal hats with $n$ hats in total. In the above example, we have $$r(78) = \frac{12}{66} \approx 0.182  $$

Moreover, define $$R = \lim_{n \to \infty} r(n). $$

**Questions**:

1. Does the value of $R$ depend on the way $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is tiled with the hat polykites, or is it always the same?
2. In case it's always the same, what is the exact value of $R$ ? And in case it can differ per tiling, what are the different possible values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ratio is $7+3\sqrt5:2$. [This blog entry at aperiodical.com](https://aperiodical.com/2023/03/an-aperiodic-monotile-exists) credits Adam Goucher for noticing that this is $\phi^4:1$ where $\phi=(\sqrt5+1)/2$. Goucher gives the figure in [this blog entry](https://cp4space.hatsya.com/2023/03/21/aperiodic-monotile/) though without proof.

[Smith](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.10798) proves that the ratio is as stated above by means of substitution rules which, if applied to a hat-tiling, produce another. The rule replaces
a hat the usual way up with an $H_8$, a patch consisting of 8 hats, 7 the usual way up and 1 flipped.
It replaces
a flipped hat with an anti-hat; that is, it replaces a usual-way-up hat and a flipped hat with an $H_7$, a patch consisting of 7 hats, 6 the usual way up and 1 flipped.

It can thus be seen that, with $\{a_i\}$ being the sequence

0, 1, 7, 48, 329, 2255, 15456, 105937, 726103, 4976784, 34111385, 233802911 (OEIS A004187)

if you have $a_{i-1}$ flipped and $a_i$ usual-way up hats, and apply the rule, you will get $a_i$ flipped and $a_{i+1}$ usual-way up hats. The sequence is obtained by the recurrence $a_0=0, a_1=1$, $a_i=7a_{i-1}-a_{i-2}$. We also have $a_i=F(4i)/3$ where $F$ denotes Fibonacci number. Hence how come the ratio is $\phi^4:1$ (the limiting ratio of successive Fibonacci numbers is $\phi:1$).

[Smith] David Smith, Joseph Samuel Myers, Craig Kaplan, and Chaim Goodman-Strauss. An aperiodic monotile.

Comment: Thank you! Could you perhaps elaborate? Is there any particular page in Smit et al.'s paper where this is mentioned? Or does Goucher describe how he arrives at this conclusion in another article?

Comment: I misremembered where I'd read the credit to Goucher. I've now corrected the reference.

Comment: Thanks for the additions!

Comment: The substitution matrix is an easier approach. The right eigenvector associated with the Perron-Frobenius eigenvalue corresponds to the relative frequencies of the tiles.

Comment: @DanRust Do you perhaps know whether this approach can also be used to determine the ratio of the flipped/normal tiles that have a certain orientation? For instance, the ones that are tilted at 60 degrees? In the video, we have at 14:44 there are 16 normal ones (blue) and 6 flipped ones (brown) that are tilted at this angle. Can one determine that ratio when $n \to \infty$ as well?

Comment: Sure just work out the substitution matrix where one considers each orientation to be a separate tile. You can similarly work out the frequencies of local patches of tiles this way.